# JQuery remove elements with id not containing a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I'm trying to implement a search algorithm on a page.

I have a table with orders, each row has an order, which has a unique ID.

Each row's `<tr>` has this ID set:

```
<tr class="searchable" id="bla_1">1</tr>
<tr class="searchable" id="bla_2">2</tr>
<tr class="searchable" id="notbla_3">3</tr>
<tr class="searchable" id="not_4">4</tr>
```

I would like to hide all the elements of class searchable which are unlike a search string. Preferably without just looking at the start. So in the example above, if my search string is "bla" it would show rows 1, 2 and 3.

I would also like to be able to use this same function on other containers, like divs:

```
<div class="searchable" id="bla_1">1</div>
<div class="searchable" id="bla_2">2</div>
<div class="searchable" id="notbla_3">3</div>
<div class="searchable" id="not_4">4</div>
```

I'm presuming I need some sort of a foreach loop, but so far I've not been able to find how to go about doing this.

Comment: `$(".searchable").hide(); $("[id*='bla']").show();`

Comment: As a side note, ID attribute should bring any data specific to element, you'd have better to use `data-*` attribute if your ID doesn't have any other meaning (e.g if not use for tageting it using hash in URI)

Comment: Just a side note: id's must be unique in the page scope. If you combine both pieces of code of your example in one page, your html won't be valid.

Comment: EDIT previous comment: ID attribute ***shouldn't*** bring any data

Comment: I know @TomB. I've changed it to order_id, i'm not sure if a custom attributename is allowed like that/best practice, but it does work.

Comment: @p.streef You should use e.g: `data-search="bla_1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
var search="bla";
$('.searchable').hide();
$('.searchable[id*="' + search + '"]').show();
```

Comment: This works great! If you add a filter checking for search == "" you can easily just show everything for an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use attribute 'contains' selector.:

```
$('.searchable[id*="' + searchString + '"]').show();
```

Where `searchString` is a variable string equals to what string you are searching for.

Answer (score 2):

```
var search; //holds the value
if(search == ""){
  $('.searchable').show();
}else{
  $('.searchable').hide();
  $('.searchable[id*="' + search + '"]').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Hide all elements containing bla in the id
$('.searchable[id*="bla"]').hide();
// Hide all elements not containing bla in the id
$('.searchable:not([id*="bla"])').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchable" id="bla_1">1</div>
<div class="searchable" id="bla_2">2</div>
<div class="searchable" id="notbla_3">3</div>
<div class="searchable" id="not_4">4</div>
```